# Getting AttributeError from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, attributeerror

I'm working on a simple Python code to make a raster from a shapefile using the Natural Neighbors tool, and then use the resulting raster to generate a contour using the Contour tool. I keep getting an Attribute Error saying the module has no attribute.

The following is my code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Variable Definitions

in_point_features = "C:\\GIS\\PythonProgramming\\Lesson3\\Lesson3_Data\\WellsSubset.shp"
z_field = "TD"
out_polyline_features = "C:\\GIS\\PythonProgramming\\Lesson3\\Lesson3_Data\\ContourOut.shp"

# Generate raster from WellsSubset shapefile using Natural Neighbor interpolation

raster = arcpy.NaturalNeighbor (in_point_features, z_field)

# Use Contour tool with 1500 as contour interval on the raster

arcpy.Contour (raster, out_polyline_features, 1500)
```

The following is the error message I get when I run it: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/GIS/PythonProgramming/Lesson3/Crotty_Homework3.py", line 15, in

```
<module>
raster = arcpy.NaturalNeighbor (in_point_features, z_field)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NaturalNeighbor'
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction here?

Comment: Did you check out the spatial analyst extension? `arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")` [Import Spatial Analyst](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/mapalgebra/importing-the-spatial-analyst-module.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You need to properly call the Spatial Analyst [license and module](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/mapalgebra/importing-the-spatial-analyst-module.htm). In your case, the syntax would be as follows:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial") # This checks out the license
from arcpy.sa import * # This imports all the SA tools

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Variable Definitions

in_point_features = "C:\\GIS\\PythonProgramming\\Lesson3\\Lesson3_Data\\WellsSubset.shp"
z_field = "TD"
out_polyline_features = "C:\\GIS\\PythonProgramming\\Lesson3\\Lesson3_Data\\ContourOut.shp"

# Generate raster from WellsSubset shapefile using Natural Neighbor interpolation

raster = NaturalNeighbor (in_point_features, z_field)

# Use Contour tool with 1500 as contour interval on the raster

Contour (raster, out_polyline_features, 1500)
```